# Плавная анимация с проверкой

Tags: javascript, jquery, animate

Есть следующая структура файлов, хочу сделать следующие - при клике на main, проверяется, если `show-title` (имеет свойство `display:block`), то ничего не делать, если при клике на `main hide-title`(имеет свойство `display:block`), то сделать анимацию до секции about-header . Не знаю как такие проверки написать :(

```
<div class=main> 
    <h4 class="show-title">Показать полностью<h4>
    <h4 class="hide-title>Свернуть<h4>
<div>


$(".hide-title").click(function() {
   $("html, body").animate({
   scrollTop : $(".about-header").offset().top
 }, 400);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
var isVisible = $('.show-title').is(":visible");
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, дайте более развёрнутый ответ, как данный код решает проблему, озвученную в вопросе.

Comment: @eugeneek ниже уже товарищ разобрался таким же методом)

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался)) вроде всё работает.

```
$(".main").click(function() {
    if ($(".show-title").is(":visible")) {
    } else {
      $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop : $(".about-header").offset().top
      }, 400);
    };
  });
```